# How to properly check if 2 edittext are equals

Tags: android-edittext, equals

I am working on a project which has a functionality of allowing the user to change its password. Once the user confirms its old password it is redirected to a new form having 2 edittext I have use .equals in comparing but cant seem to make it work. So how do you do this? Here is my code

OnCreate

```
    final EditText NewPassword = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etNewpass);
    final EditText ConfirmNewPass= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etConfirmPass);
```

Onclick

```
    final String UserInputPassword = NewPassword.getText().toString();
    final String Confirm = ConfirmNewPass.getText().toString();

    if(Confirm.equals(UserInputPassword)){
                //INSERT CODE FOR NEW PASSWORD
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"WORKINGLOGIC",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
     }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I answered your question without understanding properly,do you want to know how to check if both `String` are the same? or you want to carry these values onto the next activity?

Comment: @FayZan  sir I have fixed this issue, it turns out that this code is good, its just that my other codes affected its function. Thank you for commenting and trying to help ^^